# DBSCAN for lat long points AND nominal features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dbscan

I have a dataset that looks like the following first row:

```
Name Geometry  Restaurant  School  Hospital  Bank Auto_Repair Gas_Station Salon
Chipotle POINT(-82.458142 27.387703) 1 0  0 0 0 0 0
```

However, my actual dataset has 40,000 points and around 400 nominal features. I was able to cluster my points into around 400 clusters using DBSCAN, however this only cluster's based on distance. How can I account for my nominal features so that points such as a `Restaurant` and `Auto_Repair` shop are less likely to occur in the same cluster as `Restaurant` and `Salon`points? Would I adjust my haverstine distance matrix with a jaccard or cosine similarity matrix?

Comment: First you need to decide on which basis you want to make clusters? The location proximity or type ?

Comment: How do you intend to balance these factors? Also, at 40k points, I'd avoid anything based on a distance matrix because of O(n²) cost.